# Powershell Delete list of files from directories located on a network share

Tags: powershell, citrix, cleanup

I wrote the following script to delete all temp files and cached data from users profiles located on network share.

It works fine when I run it locally on my machine but when I attempt to run it on a network share it always fails.

This is how my script works,

1. specify a list of folder that needs cleanup names.text
2. specify the path for the directory
3. use remove-item command to delete the required files

   ```
    $userlist = Get-Content -Path "C:\Profiles\names.txt"
    $home_folders = "C:\Profiles\"


    $UserList | ForEach-Object {    
    $User_Home = $Home_Folders + "\" + $_

    Remove-Item "$User_Home\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Temp\*" -Force -Recurse 
   }
   ```

What I have done so far?

- I tried placing the path as \UNC path but that does nothing.
- I tried to remove -erroraction silentlycontinue to see what kind of errors shows up but it does nothing. like I execute the script but it just hang.
- I also tried to execute the script from the same network share but without luck.

Comment: How long are you waiting?  A command like that can take a while.

Comment: So the item you are removing will be `C:\Profiles\\someName\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Temp\*` ? Even better, instead of guessing, create a variable $itemToRemove, and use Write-Host to display each item that is removed.  Writing and debugging scripts is difficult with no logging/information.

Comment: use the debugger to step thru the script and see what line hangs

Comment: `Appdata\Local` is specifically designed for data that does not need to persist between sessions. Why not exclude `AppData\Local` and `AppData\LocalLow` in the Citrix Profile Management policy? Then you don't have to perform the cleanup in the future :)

Comment: Not a solution to your issue; but you may want to replace `$User_Home = $Home_Folders + "\" + $_` with ` $User_Home = Join-Path $Home_Folders $_`; that'll avoid any issues with additional slashes.

Comment: As previously mentioned, you have a double slash in your $User_Home variable as the script stands. I removed the added slash on the variable creation line and ran this script just fine referencing both a local drive and a UNC path. Can you be more specific about how it "fails"? Do you get errors? If so, what are they? Any information would be helpful in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Your fix worked, please submit it as an answer and I will accept it as a solution accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Great news; glad it worked; hadn't realised that it would actually resolve your issue, but glad that it did. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently appending two backslashes to your directory:

```
$home_folders = "C:\Profiles\"
#...
$User_Home = $Home_Folders + "\" + $_
```

You could get around this by removing the slash from home_folders (`$home_folders = "C:\Profiles`) or by removing it from your join (`$User_Home = $Home_Folders + $_`).

However a better way is to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet, which checks for a slash and appends one as needed:

```
$User_Home = Join-Path $Home_Folders $_
```